# Is ZeroMQ ready for production use?

Tags: messaging, zeromq

The same question was asked 1 year ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870814/is-zeromq-production-ready). I'm looking for a status update for today.

- How are the error messages, documentation, etc?
- Are there frequent bugs which cause development problems?
- How is the performance?

Comment: It's been a year since I posted this, I'd like to hear if the situation has changed.

Comment: Which version series are you talking about here? (Anyone replying, please state *exactly* what version you're using.)

Comment: I'm looking for any version that would be production ready. Let's say the latest stable release - 2.2.0

Comment: @AlexB: No it hasn't. I gave it a spin a month ago. I used 2.1.9.

Comment: @Matt:  Care to elaborate?  Any specific problems you had...perhaps you could post an answer to this question w.r.t. your experiences.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is ZeroMQ production ready?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870814/is-zeromq-production-ready)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We use `2.x` extensively in production systems in financial area:

- `2.0.11` in a mercantile exchange system (for communication from brokers to exchange gateway via `tcp`, and for communication between various components of the exchange system itself)
- `2.1.x` in other types of payment-related systems (`inproc` and `tcp` transports)

We didn't use PGM transport yet.

ZeroMQ mailing list and development team are always very helpful.