# Communication between Django web frontend and a Java daemon

Tags: java, python, django, python-2.6

Imagine, I have

1. a Django web front-end and
2. a Java daemon.

This system is used to allow to perform some complex calculations via the web.

"Some complex calculations" include

- creating a separate database for each web user,
- running native scripts on the server (again, each web user has its own directory and his own files),
- parsing files, generated by the scripts,
- cleaning up the user's directory, when the web user has logged off,
- generating images to be displayed in the web frontend.

What options exist for implementing this communication

1. from web frontend to Java daemon (like "generate image X" request) and
2. from Java daemon to web frontend (like sending the generated image back)

?

Requirements:

1. Simplicity: This system will be a prototype (proof of concept) and I'll rewrite it from scratch later (if the idea proves to be good).
2. Ease of deployment: I will update the web-frontend and the daemon very frequently.

Important note: Currently, I don't care about scalability/performance.

Comment: some web service would do I believe. SOAP for more complex messaging or REST for a quick start. Also, for message passing you may want to check  java and python seciton from below: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface#Python

Comment: You might want something like RabbitMQ. There's Celery out there for managing task queues in Python but most of the examples define the tasks in Python as well. You should be able to interoperate though I don't know for certain. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933833/interoperating-with-django-celery-from-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823705/why-use-amqp-zeromq-rabbitmq